# How would these Go structs look as Postgres tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I don't know how to write these structs as SQL tables, please help

```
type Author struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Votes int    `json:"votes"`
}

type Comment struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Author  Author `json:"author"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
    Votes   int    `json:"votes"`
}

type Post struct {
    ID        string    `json:"id"`
    Title     string    `json:"title"`
    Content   string    `json:"content"`
    Author    Author    `json:"author"`
    Comments  []Comment `json:"comments"`
    Votes     int       `json:"votes"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
}
```

I get stuck at Author and Comments because in go it's an array of a struct...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
  id CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  author ??? NOT NULL, --  what goes here
  comments ??? NOT NULL, -- and here
  votes int NOT NULL, 
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: [Don't use CHAR](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)  - and if ID is in fact a UUID, the datatype of the column should be `uuid` anyways, not some character type. title, content, author can all be defined as `text`. Where does the number 255 come from? Do you have a business requirement to limit the content to just 255 characters?

Comment: `Author` and `Comment` should have their own tables in the database. Then in the `posts` table `author` should be `author_id <type> not null references <authors_table> (id)`. And the `post`-`comment` relationships would be defined by having the `comments` table declare a column that points to the `posts` table, i.e. `post_id <type> not null references posts (id)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name shit idk just messing around

Comment: oo ok so something like this: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts ( id UUID PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL, content TEXT NOT NULL, author_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES authors (id), created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL, );` `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments ( id UUID PRIMARY KEY, post_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES posts (id), author_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES posts (id), content TEXT NOT NULL, votes INTEGER NOT NULL, );` `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authors ( id UUID PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, votes INTEGER NOT NULL );`

Answer (score 3):

So you've added postgres and sql. So not sure which one you are using, but assuming its PostgreSQL version 11+

This is how it would look as a diagram, with the relationships your structs describe.

[image: ERD Diagram]

```
Author is one to many comments
Author is one to many posts

A Post has many comments
A Post has one author

A comment belongs to a post
A comment belongs to an author

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authors (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  votes INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES posts(id),
  author_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES authors(id),
  content VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  votes INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  author_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES authors(id),
  votes INT NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);
```

A couple of things I'd look at your design though. As you sure a post would only have a single author?
Content could be quite large on a comment, do you want to limit this to 255 or more? If so you'd probably want this as TEXT?